# How do I remove old version of plugins in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I'm trying to update my plugins but when I do I get the following. It seems as though I need to delete older version of the plugins before I can update. However, searching in the eclipse folders (configuration, dropins, p2, plugins, features) does not find any files related to the older plugins. What do I need to do to solve this?

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: XSD - XML Schema Definition Model 2.7.0.v20110606-0949 (org.eclipse.xsd.feature.group 2.7.0.v20110606-0949)
  Software currently installed: Oracle Coherence Tools 1.7.3.201107052022 (oracle.eclipse.tools.helios.coherence.feature.group 1.7.3.201107052022)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.6.2.r362_v20101117-0800-7z8XFW6FLFlmjJcvz03jyeFBLS_F (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.6.2.r362_v20101117-0800-7z8XFW6FLFlmjJcvz03jyeFBLS_F)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Debug Core 3.7.0.v20110518 (org.eclipse.debug.core 3.7.0.v20110518)
    Debug Core 3.6.0.v20100519 (org.eclipse.debug.core 3.6.0.v20100519)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.3.0.v20100503 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.3.0.v20100503)
    Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.4.1.R37x_v20110725 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.4.1.R37x_v20110725)
    Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.4.0.v20110502 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.4.0.v20110502)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Oracle Coherence Tools UI 3.2.3.201107052022 (oracle.eclipse.tools.coherence.ui 3.2.3.201107052022)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.debug.core [3.6.0,3.7.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem is here:

```
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Oracle Coherence Tools UI 3.2.3.201107052022 (oracle.eclipse.tools.coherence.ui 3.2.3.201107052022)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.debug.core [3.6.0,3.7.0)
```

The version of the Oracle Coherence Tools UI you're trying to install is built for Eclipse 3.6 (Helios), but you're running Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo).

Perhaps there's a later version of the plugin you could use? If not, you might have to revert to an older version of Eclipse.

Comment: Another option would be to remove the Oracle Coherence Tools and then install whatever it is you're trying to install now.

Comment: I thought the problem was that I had to remove the old version of Debug Core. You're saying that's the wrong thing to do and that I should look at the other section instead?

Comment: The message is saying that Coherence Tools requires org.eclipse.debug.core from Eclipse 3.6 (and no later), and this requirement is inconsistent with the feature you're trying to install. Removing Coherence Tools as Eric suggests will allow a later version of the debug.core bundle to be used.

Comment: Let me guess...the "and no later" is implied by the "[" instead of using a "(" ?
There's a whole list of "Cannot satisfy dependency". I should work that list and then that will take case of the "Only one of the following" ?

Comment: The `[3.6.0` denotes an inclusive lower bound (>=3.6.0). The `)` denotes an exclusive upper bound (<3.7.0). So the "and no later" comes from the part after the comma.

Comment: Good explanations, so thanks, but the versions seemed so mixed together I just deleted eclipse and reinstalled the latest version.